# Why snap dependency management is so broken?

Tags: snap

snap has 2 modules: snap-store and gnome-3-28-1804, the first one depends on the second.

Yet when I use `$ snap remove gnome-3-28-1804`, I got no error information: no warning of consequence, no prompt to remove snap-store, no nothing.

So obviously the next time I use snap-store I got the following error:

```
$ snap-store 
/home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
/home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so
/home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
/home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/peng/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so
20:09:52:0025 Gtk Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
20:09:52:0155 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
20:09:52:0163 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
20:09:52:0167 GLib-GIO Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
20:09:52:0221 Gs  enabled plugins: odrs, rewrite-resource, snap, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
20:09:52:0221 Gs  disabled plugins: appstream, desktop-categories, desktop-menu-path, dpkg, dummy, epiphany, fedora-pkgdb-collections, generic-updates, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-featured, hardcoded-popular, modalias, os-release, provenance, provenance-license, repos, shell-extensions
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
20:09:52:0342 Gtk Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/188/data-dir/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Aborted
```

My question is: why snap chose to make such a low level mistake?

Comment: Not sure why ask here. If you think it is a bug, file a bug report.

Comment: Usually snaps are started with `snap run snap-name`, maybe this makes a difference. The names of needed dependencies are stored in the `.yaml`-file and if missing probably installed when using correct command, tough I never ran into this problem so can't be sure.